# Sharepoint web part POST

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, http, post

It's easy to create a hyperlink that passes parameters using GET by adding them to the URL:

http:\somesite.com?name=fred

but the web service I'm connecting to uses POST. What's the best way to do this in Sharepoint?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm not surprised there's no answer to this. I suspect I'm probably approaching this in the wrong way and not explaining it well.

I want to take the user's browser to a diffent page passing POST data, like a HTML form would. But in sharepoint you can't change the 'action=' - you can only post back to the same page - if I understand the page life cycle bit correctly.

I'll try adding a button to the web part and use it's onclick() to do a HTTP web request.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to post data differently, adding a second form element to the page should work. It needs to be outside the SharePoint form, but adding another element outside that is easy enough with javascript/jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for that, but all the docs I've found say only 1 active form can be rendered.

Managed in the end by adding a button witha different post back url and a few hidden vars:

this.wpmButton.PostBackUrl = "aserver.com";
this.Page.Form.Method = "POST";
this.Page.RegisterHiddenField("Item", "Value");

Comment: The single form restriction is in ASP.NET (and even then there are a number of exceptions). The version I suggested is pure html, so ASP.NET restrictions don't apply.